# Json.NET - correct way to vary schema/contract based on values?

Tags: json.net

I'm serialising JSON for inclusion in a search index (Elasticsearch).

One of the properties I'm serialising is logger state, which can include any objects.  I limit the depth of recursion and handle serialisation errors.  The problem I have, however, is that different objects/types may have members named the same but with a different type.

For instance, I might serialise `{ scope: { query: "?hello=true" } }` for one type and `{ scope: { query: { userId: 123 } } }` for another.

Elasticsearch doesn't like this, so my idea is, for the parts of the resulting object which are *user-defined*, I'll use different property names, so they each get their own index field, corresponding to their type.

I'm thinking of either translating the two examples above into:

`{ scope: { query_str: "?hello=true" } }` and `{ scope: { query_obj: { userId_num: 123 } } }`

or

`{ scope: { query: { str: "?hello=true" } } }` and `{ scope: { query: { obj: { userId: { num: 123 } } } } }`

Almost certainly the former.. however, it seems within Json.NET internals there's not a way to vary a property name based on the property value at runtime.

I can't override the internal serialiser writer's object and dictionary serialisation, and there doesn't seem to be an extension point to do this.

Approaches I thought of:

1. Use reflection to build nested dictionaries in advance - fiddly and complex, and wouldn't do the clever stuff Json.NET does with data contracts, dynamics, etc..
2. Create a wrapping `JsonTextWriter` which looks at `Path` etc to make the changes at a low level
3. After the initial serialisation, deserialise, re-organise, and serialise again

None seem great.  What's my best option?

Edit: test case -

```
    public class A
    {
        public int Num { get; set; }
    }

    [Fact]
    public void JsonFieldNamesMangled()
    {
        var entry = new Dictionary<string, object>()
        {
            { "abc", "def" },
            {
                "scope", new
                {
                    SomeString1 = "hello",
                    SomeInt1 = 12,
                    SomeArr1 = new[] { 1, 2 }
                }
            }
        };
        entry["state"] = new Dictionary<string, object>
        {
            { "SomeString2", "goodbye" },
            { "SomeInt2", 34 },
            { "SomeArr2", new[] { new A { Num = 1 }, new A { Num = 2 } } }
        };

        var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(entry);
        // original: "{\"abc\":\"def\",\"scope\":{\"SomeString1\":\"hello\",\"SomeInt1\":12,\"SomeArr1\":[1,2]},\"state\":{\"SomeString2\":\"goodbye\",\"SomeInt2\":34,\"SomeArr2\":[{\"Num\":1},{\"Num\":2}]}}");
        json.Should().Be("{\"abc\":\"def\",\"scope\":{\"SomeString1_str\":\"hello\",\"SomeInt1_num\":12,\"SomeArr1_arr_num\":[1,2]},\"state\":{\"SomeString2_str\":\"goodbye\",\"SomeInt2_num\":34,\"SomeArr2_arr_obj\":[{\"Num_num\":1},{\"Num_num\":2}]}}");
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option would be to implement your own [custom `JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverter.htm) whose [`WriteJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_WriteJson.htm) method re-implements some minimal, necessary subset of the logic of [`JsonSerializerInternalWriter.SerializeObject()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L438) while also remapping property names based on the property value type:

```
public abstract class JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverterBase : JsonConverter
{
    public override bool CanRead { get { return false; } }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    protected abstract string ResolvePropertyName(JsonSerializer serializer, JsonProperty property, object value);

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        var contract = (JsonObjectContract)serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());

        writer.WriteStartObject();
        foreach (var property in contract.Properties)
        {
            if (!property.Readable || property.Ignored || (property.ShouldSerialize != null && !property.ShouldSerialize(value)))
                continue;
            var propertyValue = property.ValueProvider.GetValue(value);
            if (propertyValue == null && serializer.NullValueHandling == NullValueHandling.Ignore)
                continue;
            //Todo if required:
            //serializer.DefaultValueHandling, serializer.PreserveReferencesHandling, serializer.ReferenceLoopHandling, serializer.TypeNameHandling
            //property.Converter, property.ItemConverter
            var name = ResolvePropertyName(serializer, property, propertyValue);
            writer.WritePropertyName(name);
            serializer.Serialize(writer, propertyValue);
        }
        writer.WriteEndObject();
    }
}

public class JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter : JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverterBase
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("This converter should be applied via [JsonConverter(typeof(JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter)]");
    }

    protected override string ResolvePropertyName(JsonSerializer serializer, JsonProperty property, object value)
    {
        // Replace with whatever logic you want here.
        if (value == null)
            return property.PropertyName;
        var contract = serializer.ContractResolver.ResolveContract(value.GetType());
        string type;
        if (contract is JsonObjectContract)
            type = "obj";
        else if (contract is JsonArrayContract)
            type = "array";
        else if (value is string)
            type = "str";
        else if (value is Int32)
            type = "num";
        else
            type = value.GetType().Name.ToLowerInvariant();
        return property.PropertyName + "_" + type;
    }
}

public class JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter<T> : JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter
{
    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return typeof(T).IsAssignableFrom(objectType);
    }
}
```

Then you could apply it to your model like so:

```
[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter))]
public class Scope
{
    public object Query { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public Scope Scope { get; set; }
}

[JsonConverter(typeof(JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter))]
class Id
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
}
```

Or apply it in settings like so:

```
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver(),
    NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore,
    Converters = { new JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter<Scope>(), new JsonObjectPropertyNameRemappingConverter<Id>() },
};
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(root, Formatting.Indented, settings);
```

Notes:

- The converter implements option #1.
- The converter uses Json.NET's [contract resolver](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_IContractResolver.htm) to perform all necessary reflection.  This simplifies the logic, automatically supports camel casing, and should improve performance via caching of reflection metadata.
- Dictionaries and types that implement `ISerializable` are not supported by the converter.
- [`ReadJson()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConverter_ReadJson.htm) is not implemented (and it's not clear how it could be implemented.)

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/uBBLLq).

Comment: That is comprehensive, very clear and very helpful, thank you. A difficulty I have is that the scope is effectively a collection of user-passed objects - it's really everything contained within the scope object that should be transformed.  In fact (this is net .NET Core logging fwork), scope is typically a dictionary itself. Is there a way forward with that in mind? - probably should have elaborated in my question, sorry

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - Writing a `JsonConverter` for `Dictionary<string, object>` that modifies property names based on value type should be straightforward.  Beyond that I'd need to see some more detail in the question to rewrite the answer, ideally a [mcve].

Comment: Ok great, I'll try to put something together. I have half a unit test set up for this with everything required. Thanks for the help so far, appreciate it

Comment: I've added a test case. I'm not expecting a full solution! I think arrays will be particularly tricky for instance. But any further ideas of approach would be great, if you had some time. Thanks @dbc

Comment: I have cobbled something together which uses the same concept you outlined, although I want to conditionally apply this based on the path within the source object. Is it best for the converter to check the JsonWriter path in WriteJson and just not rename props in the case it doesn't begin with some specified path? A bit uneasy about having a converter with that much power/not being able to just return false somewhere

Comment: I've been using and working through various corner-cases here, but have come unstuck with reference loops. I don't have access to `_serializeStack` in my converter, and the `writer.Serialize` call simply doesn't write anything when it gets to a loop, and so gets into an invalid state when looping through writing properties.  Outside of reflection, is there anything I can try?

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - So, [`CheckForCircularReference()`](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/blob/master/Src/Newtonsoft.Json/Serialization/JsonSerializerInternalWriter.cs#L289) is returning false for something?   I guess I'd need to see a [mcve].  How do you want the reference loop to be handled, anyway?

Comment: It's `private` unfortunately.  I'm currently doing an imitation of it by reflecting to find `_serializeStack`.  The code you kindly crafted and shared had a `//todo` about reference loop handling, but the implementation seems very difficult with everything being internal to the writer.  I'm half-thinking of putting a git repo / NuGet package out there with this in, with the tests I have.  It's gotten a fair bit hackier as I've run into more and more that the original won't serialise.  (I'm very grateful by the way, it's working exceptionally well for the most part!)

Comment: Sorry, I meant it's not returning false, but the writer that puts out dictionaries, objects etc in the converter is basically a copy of the logic in that class, and so doesn't have access to its private members. So when I call the "inner" serialize routing, that sees the reference loop, outputs nothing, and gets the FSM into the wrong state for the next property write.

Comment: @KierenJohnstone - I'm not going to be able to look at this for a while.  You could try to create a custom contract resolver, override [`CreateObjectContract`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_DefaultContractResolver_CreateObjectContract.htm), and for objects marked with an appropriate attribute, remove all the properties, and instead...

Comment: ...  add a custom [`JsonObjectContract.ExtensionDataGetter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Serialization_JsonObjectContract_ExtensionDataGetter.htm) that returns an `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<Object, Object>>` with the remapped names and property values.  Possibly extension data values work correctly with circular reference handling, though I haven't checked.

Comment: that's no problem.  I have it all working and will probably try to make an open-source repo somewhere soon so it's easier to reason with etc. Thanks for the help so far!